# Where to put cleanup code in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController subclass that loads a bunch of images for each cell in a tableview asynchronously which is handled by a separate download class. I keep a list of all of these download requests in a dictionary which is keyed to the index of the cell that is requesting the image.

My question is i where should i put the code that cancels the image download if the viewcontroller is popped off the navcontroller? I need to do this because if the user hits back while there are still images being downloaded (which could take a while) then when they are finished downloading the viewcontroller has already been released.

I cant put it in the viewWillDisappear method because i do not want to stop the download if the user clicks on a separate tab and only when the hit the back button. For now i put this code in the viewcontrollers dealloc method which works fine although it doesnt seem right for some reason. I thought of using the viewDidUnload method but it seems this is only called when there is a low memory warning?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dealloc` is the perfect place for this as the view controller gets deallocated and you are responsible to clean your stuff up.

Comment: Hi, thx for the quick response. Does this include things like enumerating through a dictionary and calling a method for each object it contains? Just never seen code other than [someobject release] inside dealloc.

Comment: In general, -dealloc should unregister for any "delegate-like" thing you've previously registered for. `foo.delegate = nil` and  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]` are particularly common. If you ever use -scrollToRect:animated: or -zoomToRect:animated: (or whatever they're called), you may also need to set `scrollView.delegate = nil`; annoyingly, the "animation" continues even if the scroll view isn't in the view hierarchy. Perhaps they've fixed this...

Comment: @James Do whatever cleanup you have to do in dealloc. This can also be calling other objects or saving your current state.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider putting the code in `viewWillDisappear:` anyway, after all if the screen you are navigating to needs anything loaded it will be slowed by the background image load...

Comment: `viewWillDisappear ` is deprecated and no longer called.

Comment: @SylvainG. : Where did you read viewWillDissapear is depreciated and not called?  It is very much not deprecated, and still called as of iOS 11 view controllers I have been writing.  I am pretty sure a LOT of apps would break if they disabled this call. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear